# grab screenshot of a image using python of a specific place using coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot

I am trying to do template matching subimage(small.png)(Shopping icon) in the main image(map image). There are many subimage present inside the main image. With the following code, i could able to extract the single coordinate of the subimage in the main image.

I want to extract all the coordinates of the sub image present inside the main image and also want to make the template matched visible. Please kindly help me in the same

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
image = cv2.imread("Large.png")  
template = cv2.imread("small.png")  
result = cv2.matchTemplate(image,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)  
print np.unravel_index(result.argmax(),result.shape)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooNZB.png
```

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. I cannot tell if you want to make a screen-grab, or you want to display something, or you want to do template matching. Please try and improve it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell I have modified the description. Basically i am trying to do template matching and want the coordinates of the template matched images and make the template matched visible

Comment: It would be good if you could provide the images too.

Comment: @Mark Setchelll. Consider i took a google maps screenshot and i want to template match all the shopping icons present in that screenshot